# get first elements of clusters and clusters ids kmeans spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

I trained a k means model with my dataset and now I would like to get a few elements from each clusters along with the cluster id

```
val clusters = KMeans.train(data, numClusters, numIterations)

val vectorsAndClusterIdx = data.map{ point =>
  val prediction = clusters.predict(point)
  (point.toString, prediction)
}
```

But then once I have that, I don't know how to print these elements with their clusters ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you, you want to print each point with its assigned cluster id.

You could try something like this:

```
    vectorsAndClusterIdx.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

Or maybe it would be better:

```
    println(dataClustered.collect().mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: thank you, your first solution works great :) Just what I would like, if possible, to get 10 elements from each clusters

Comment: I am, but not completely, what I mean is that I would appreciate to get only 10 elements from each clusters, if possible, and not all the elements

Comment: I haven't tested it but try something like:
`vectorsAndClusterIdx.keyBy(_._2).groupByKey().flatMapValues(x => x.take(10)).values.collect().foreach(println(_))`